# Any way to dynamically insert linebreaks depending on the length of the string?

Tags: python

I receive some data in one long string from my endpoint, and depending on the length of the string I'd like to split it up into paragraphs on the frontend.

One string might look like this:

```
"*1* No princípio Deus criou os céus e a terra.*2* Era a terra sem forma e vazia; trevas cobriam a face do abismo, e o Espírito de Deus se movia sobre a face das águas.*3* Disse Deus: \"Haja luz\", e houve luz.*4* Deus viu que a luz era boa, e separou a luz das trevas.*5* Deus chamou à luz dia, e às trevas chamou noite. Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o primeiro dia.*6* Depois disse Deus: \"Haja entre as águas um firmamento que separe águas de águas\".*7* Então Deus fez o firmamento e separou as águas que estavam embaixo do firmamento das que estavam por cima. E assim foi.*8* Ao firmamento Deus chamou céu. Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o segundo dia.*9* E disse Deus: \"Ajuntem-se num só lugar as águas que estão debaixo do céu, e apareça a parte seca\". E assim foi.*10* À parte seca Deus chamou terra, e chamou mares ao conjunto das águas. E Deus viu que ficou bom.*11* Então disse Deus: \"Cubra-se a terra de vegetação: plantas que dêem sementes e árvores cujos frutos produzam sementes de acordo com as suas espécies\". E assim foi.*12* A terra fez brotar a vegetação: plantas que dão sementes de acordo com as suas espécies, e árvores cujos frutos produzem sementes de acordo com as suas espécies. E Deus viu que ficou bom.*13* Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o terceiro dia.*14* Disse Deus: \"Haja luminares no firmamento do céu para separar o dia da noite. Sirvam eles de sinais para marcar estações, dias e anos,*15* e sirvam de luminares no firmamento do céu para iluminar a terra\". E assim foi.*16* Deus fez os dois grandes luminares: o maior para governar o dia e o menor para governar a noite; fez também as estrelas.*17* Deus os colocou no firmamento do céu para iluminar a terra,*18* governar o dia e a noite, e separar a luz das trevas. E Deus viu que ficou bom.*19* Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o quarto dia.*20* Disse também Deus: \"Encham-se as águas de seres vivos, e sobre a terra voem aves sob o firmamento do céu\".*21* Assim Deus criou os grandes animais aquáticos e os demais seres vivos que povoam as águas, de acordo com as suas espécies; e todas as aves, de acordo com as suas espécies. E Deus viu que ficou bom.*22* Então Deus os abençoou, dizendo: \"Sejam férteis e multipliquem-se! Encham as águas dos mares! E multipliquem-se as aves na terra\".*23* Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o quinto dia.*24* E disse Deus: \"Produza a terra seres vivos de acordo com as suas espécies: rebanhos domésticos, animais selvagens e os demais seres vivos da terra, cada um de acordo com a sua espécie\". E assim foi.*25* Deus fez os animais selvagens de acordo com as suas espécies, os rebanhos domésticos de acordo com as suas espécies, e os demais seres vivos da terra de acordo com as suas espécies. E Deus viu que ficou bom.*26* Então disse Deus: \"Façamos o homem à nossa imagem, conforme a nossa semelhança. Domine ele sobre os peixes do mar, sobre as aves do céu, sobre os animais grandes de toda a terra e sobre todos os pequenos animais que se movem rente ao chão\".*27* Criou Deus o homem à sua imagem, à imagem de Deus o criou; homem e mulher os criou.*28* Deus os abençoou, e lhes disse: \"Sejam férteis e multipliquem-se! Encham e subjuguem a terra! Dominem sobre os peixes do mar, sobre as aves do céu e sobre todos os animais que se movem pela terra\".*29* Disse Deus: \"Eis que lhes dou todas as plantas que nascem em toda a terra e produzem sementes, e todas as árvores que dão frutos com sementes. Elas servirão de alimento para vocês.*30* E dou todos os vegetais como alimento a tudo o que tem em si fôlego de vida: a todos os grandes animais da terra, a todas as aves do céu e a todas as criaturas que se movem rente ao chão\". E assim foi.*31* E Deus viu tudo o que havia feito, e tudo havia ficado muito bom. Passaram-se a tarde e a manhã; esse foi o sexto dia.",
```

Whereas another string is way shorter:

```
"*1* Assim foram concluídos os céus e a terra, e tudo o que neles há.*2* No sétimo dia Deus já havia concluído a obra que realizara, e nesse dia descansou.
```

Obviously, the second string wouldn't need any splitting up seeing as it only has two "sections" (notice the `*1*` and `*2*` , but the first one goes from `*1*` all the way up to `*29*`

Not exactly sure what kind of logic I'm after, but maybe something along the lines of

For every `*10*th` section, add a linebreak evenly across the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

*Not exactly sure what kind of logic I'm after*

Take loot at [`textwrap.fill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.fill) function from built-in module `textwrap`. Most basic usage is providing text and giving width, for example

```
import textwrap
text = "Some very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
text_with_breaks = textwrap.fill(text, 50)
print(text_with_breaks)
```

output

```
Some very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very
very very very very very very very very very very
very very very long text
```

But it does have also many options which you can tweak, see [`textwrap.TextWrapper` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.TextWrapper).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Can it also make sure to not break a number (`*x*`) off from its corresponding text? I wouldn't want it to break it like: `"*1* \n No princípi`.

Either ` \n *1* No princip.....` or ` *1* No princip..... \n`, but never between a number and its text

Comment: @erikvm I do not know handy option for that, as workaround you might replace spaces following `*1*` using other character which do not exist in your string, apply `textwrap.fill`, then change selected character back to spaces.

Answer (score -1):

A good starting point might be using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

The following method assumes that every section begins with the pattern "***integer*** " and each section does not contain this pattern as content.

```py
import re


# your long string
string = ""

# regular expression
pattern = "(\*\d+\* .+?)(?=\*\d+\*|$)"

# using the regular expression to find all sections
sections = re.findall(pattern, string)

# now you can loop over all sections like
for section in sections:
    pass

# and let the fronted handle the display
```